# Left margin of lists beside a floating box

Tags: html, css, list, css-float

I would like to position a list beside a floating box. The Problem ist, that the bullet points of the list items are displayed outside the principal block box. So the text of the items is aligned with the normal text, but not the bullet points.

[image: floating box beneath ul]
Here's the code example: http://codepen.io/Juuro/pen/oelqm

If I use `list-style-position: inside;` it works as expected for items which are single-lined. 
Another solution would be to put the whole list in a additional box or give it `display: inline-block;`. But then the list items would float around the box anymore.

My requirements are:

- Bullet points beside the floating box should indent like without a floating box.
- In multi-line items the bullet-point should stay "outside" of the text.
- The list should still float.

Is that even possible?

Comment: you want the list to drop below the picture as above, or the whole list to be on the right? * if you do want to drop below than I agree with @SKeurentjes .. just add another 10 pixels to the margin right of the image

Comment: may increase margin ?

Comment: I neither want the list below the picture nor the whole list on the right. Who is @SKeurentjes ?

Comment: An increase of margin doesn't help because it doesn't affect the list beside the box but the list below the box. The list below the box is already as I want it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ueaiy

It seems your li in the stylesheet was inside the ul.

Comment: No, it's not. The bullet points should still be outside of the ontinuous text of the list item. The `li` was inside the `ul` because I used SCSS. I included the `list-style: inside;` as comment to show that I already thought of that and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

seeing your example and if not indented to decide what you can specify dimensions of the container tightly with a picture like this [DEMO](http://codepen.io/Juuro/pen/oelqm)

```
.imagebox {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  height: 200px;/**add**/
  width: 170px; /**add**/
}
```

or in this class to the IMG tag to set a fixed size

Comment: Your demo does only work because of the `list-style: inside;`.

Comment: and width of 150 and not 170 pixels

Comment: I checked your example